# Calling Jupyter Notebook function from python file using Node Red

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, node-red

I am having some data upon which I have applied Machine Leaning and trained models using Jupyter Notebook. Now I want to test real values on this model so that I can get predictions for real values. I am able to test model with sample values inside Jupyter Notebook and it is working fine. But, in actual setup, the real values come from sensors which are received by Node Red and I want to pass those values to Jupyter Notebook and get resulting predictions.

In my .ipynb fie I have many other functions (likes the one training on datasets) that I do not want to execute once the training is complete since models are already trained. I only want to call specific function inside .ipynb file. So I created a custom function inside same .ipynb file which takes values and predicts result.

Now to call this specific function only, I created a second Jupyter Notebook file (.ipynb) and imported main file inside second ipynb file using following code:

`from ipynb.fs.full.firstFile import specificFunction`

`specificFunction("passed real values here")`

Second Notebook successfully calls specific function and code runs perfectly.

To be able to pass values using Node Red to this second Notebook. So I converted this second Notebook to .py file using Jupyter Notebook File > Download as > .py and called this py file using Node Red EXEC Node (used to execute commands).

Following is Node Red Exec node command:

`python "D:\Jupyter Notebooks\secondNotebook.py"`

It is not executing and giving error as command failed. To debug, I have tested simple python file by only printing 'hello world' inside that python file, it is executing successfully. Only this specific file is throwing error as "command failed"

Any suggestions and solutions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is the error given (both in the editor and in the node-red logs). Also what happens if you try and run `python "D:\Jupyter Notebooks\secondNotebook.py"` in the cmd shell?

Comment: If i run ```python "D:\Jupyter Notebooks\secondNotebook.py"```, It is  not running only function that is being called. It starts executing firstNotebook from start to End. No matter what.